# Export PEM from Keychain on Mac with SAN (Subject Alternative Name)

Tags: macos, ssl, keychain, pem

Is there any way to export a key from the Keychain in Mac and assign it a SAN (Subject Alternative Name) at the same time? I need to provide a SAM for 10.0.2.2. It is for Android development where the emulator is localhost and the computer hosting the emulator with the Web APIs on it is mapped to 10.0.2.2.

I read an article on doing with with Open SSL ([Connecting mobile apps to backends for development with SSL](https://medium.com/@noumaan/ssl-app-dev-a2923d5113c6)), but need to do it with a certificate already in Keychain.  My development machine is already running with a self-signed certificate and the Web API layer is working fine.

Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: You cannot modify a certificate (it's signed, and any modification will invalidate the signature). You could create a new certificate using the same key, but if you're creating a new cert anyway, I can't think of a reason not to just create a new key for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gordon Davisson's answer is correct. I created a new key using openssl.